# How to query data with multithreading all 50ms in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I will query data from machine all 50ms per query. I have a map with the id's for query. For one id, I create one Thread. In the end I have 500 thread.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, NodeId[]> entry1 : nodeIds.entrySet()) {
    try {
        NodeId[] entrNodeIds = entry1.getValue();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                new ReadRegisteredValues().getValue(entry1.getKey(), entrNodeIds[0], client);
            };
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fileLogger.error("failed read node: " + entry1.getKey());
    }
}
```

After this I read in every thread with a `while(true)` the values every 50ms, like this:

```
public void getValue(String nodeName, NodeId registeredNodeId, UaClient client) {

    while (true) {
        try {
            DataValue value = null;
            try {
                value = client.readAttribute(registeredNodeId, Attributes.Value);
            } catch (ServiceException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (StatusException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            TeocModel curTeocModel = new TeocModel(value.getSourceTimestamp().getTimeInMillis(), nodeName, value);
            KafkaStreamer.getInstance().startStreaming(curTeocModel.toJson());

            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            fileLogger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case, I read the values not parallel. Is this the best method to query data parallel?

any idea?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve in the end. Do you actually need to read each node separately, or is it ok to iterate through all of them every 50ms? (although Thread.sleep(50) is definitely the wrong way to do this).

Comment: did not understand need for while loop and thread.sleep() inside the getValue() method. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You can also leverage by the way with ThreadPool classes , which will make it more efficient.

Comment: @daniu i need to read each node seperately an each node are must read every 50ms

Comment: @ramasCoder i read in the while loop every 50ms the the node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ScheduledExecutorService to do the scheduling for you.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(parallelism);
for (Map.Entry<String, NodeId[]> entry1 : nodeIds.entrySet()) {
    Runnable checkNode = () -> getValue(entry1.getKey(), entrNodeIds[0], client);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkNode, 50, 50, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
}
```

Remove the while loop and the `Thread.sleep()` in your `getValue` for this.

```
public void getValue(String nodeName, NodeId registeredNodeId, UaClient client) {

    try {
        DataValue value = null;
        try {
            value = client.readAttribute(registeredNodeId, Attributes.Value);
        } catch (ServiceException | StatusException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        TeocModel curTeocModel = new TeocModel(value.getSourceTimestamp().getTimeInMillis(), nodeName, value);
        KafkaStreamer.getInstance().startStreaming(curTeocModel.toJson());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        fileLogger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now the update will be executed every 50ms from one of the threads. Note that if the update takes too long and there are too many updates, the execution queue will grow forever and you'll run into some sort of resource problem eventually.

Comment: tried it, it works but with 500threads and 500 querys every 50ms not possible?

500 querys every 50ms it looks like this:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnWUmBpk49FJnM4tQ_segBCYj5AYiA

50 querys every 50ms it looks like this:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnWUmBpk49FJnM4sTtLOHCje1B31JQ

why? is my pc to slow, need i more power?

Comment: @ofitz It depends on how fast your getValue is, but I think it does sound doubtful you can do 500/50ms this way.

Comment: My getValue is 14ms fast and the machine can process 1000 querys parallel.  So i think i need more computer power to get 500values/querys every 50ms